# Sticky footer navbar and centred login panel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This question has been asked already several times for every single component as below:

- How to keep the navbar fixed
- How to keep the footer fixed
- How to centre div at the middle of the page

What I am trying to achieve is to have all together at the same time

I want to centre a login panel in the middle of the page (horizontally and vertically) but I have some issues with the footer

- I want the page to render correctly on mobile phones. The login area should never be underneath header or footer.
- When the page is displayed I want the footer to be displayed. At the moment I need to scroll down to see the footer. Too much space between the login form and the footer. Footer needs to stay fixed at the bottom.
- The login form if possible should be wider and taller

Thank you for your help

This is the critical part I need to figure out how to configure

```
/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 140px 0 -200px 0;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0;
}
```

Please see jfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gn1sk3ne/) for your information

At the moment

```
___________________________________________________     _ Visible Page 
|Navbar                                           |      |
|                                                 |      |
|_________________________________________________|      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                      ^                          |      |
|                      |  Too much space          |      |
|                      |                          |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                _______________                  |      |    
|               |               |                 |      |
|               |  Login Area   |                 |      |  
|               |_______________|                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                      ^                          |     _| 
|                      |  Too much space          |
|                      |                          |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|                                                 |
|_________________________________________________|
| Footer                                          |
|_________________________________________________|
```

What I want

```
___________________________________________________     _ Visible Page 
|Navbar                                           |      |
|                                                 |      |
|_________________________________________________|      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|              _____________________              |      |    
|             |                     |             |      |
|             |                     |             |      |
|             |    Login Area       |             |      |  
|             |                     |             |      |
|             |_____________________|             |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|                                                 |      |
|_________________________________________________|      |
| Footer                                          |      |
|_________________________________________________|     _|
```

Comment: I had a little play with media queries and your original CSS. Is this any closer to what you wish to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/gn1sk3ne/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting approach based on CSS3's `calc` and viewport-related units: `vh` and `vw`:

```css
/* In the below @media queries I set body's background to red, in real application appropriate steps should be taken to fit the key elements of webpage and exclude all others */
/* Minimum width we need is 300px (width of login form) */
@media all and (max-width: 300px){
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
/* Minimum height we need is 140px (height of login form plus heights of nav and footer) */
@media all and (max-height: 140px){
  body {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 20px;
}
main {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
  /*
  Margin from top and bottom:
    half of viewport's height minus
    half of login form's height minus
    half of sum of nav's and footer's heights
  Margin from left and right:
    half of viewport's width minus
    half of login form's width
  */
  margin: calc(50vh - 50px - 20px) calc(50vw - 150px);
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
footer {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</nav>
<main>
  Login form<br/>
  Login form<br/>
  Login form<br/>
  Login form<br/>
  Login form
</main>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

**[View in codepen.com](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMYvQw?editors=1100)**.

---

Support is pretty decent:

- `calc` is supported by IE9+, Edge, Firefox 16+ (4+ with prefix), Chrome 26+ (19+ with prefix), Opera 15+, Safari 6.1+ (6+ with prefix) ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility)).
- `vh` and `vw` are supported by IE9+, Edge, Firefox 19+, Chrome 20+, Opera 15+, Safari 6+ ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Browser_compatibility)).

---

Graphical explanation of `calc`s' values:

[image]

---

This approach is not the most elegant one, but maybe it will satisfy you.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do it. See a working bootply example [here](http://www.bootply.com/CTXCTNNzVL).

```css
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}


/* Custom page CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */


#wrap > .container {
  padding: 60px 15px 0;
}
.container .credit {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#footer > .container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

#footer {
 position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}

.center{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background:red;
    top:calc(50% - 50px/2); /* height divided by 2*/
    left:calc(50% - 50px/2); /* width divided by 2*/
}
```

```html
<!-- Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
  
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="center">
     login goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted credit">Centered login footer.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you vertically and horizontally centre the login area inside the main body?

Comment: I updated my example. See class `.center` or on bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/CTXCTNNzVL).